# document.querySelector is not selecing the elements and throws ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, document, queryselector

I would really appreciate the help.
**document.querySelector** doesn't select the elements and throws ReferenceError: **document is not defined** - on vscode console, and Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined in the devtools console (that's the same problem cause "document.querySelector" is not selecting anything.)
My script tag is at the end of the body tag.
What could be causing the error?

```js
const inputBox = document.querySelector('.inputField input');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.inputField button');

inputBox.onkeyup = () => {
  let userData = inputBox.value;
  if (userData.trim() !== 0) {
    addBtn.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    addBtn.classList.remove("active");
  }
}

//if user click on the add button 
addBtn.onclick = () => {
  let userData = inputBox.value;
  let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
  if (getLocalStorage == null) {
    listArr = [];
  } else {
    listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage);
  }
  listArr.push(userData);
  localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArr));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>to-do-list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Todo App</header>
    <div class="inputField">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add here...">
      <button><span class="lnr lnr-plus-circle"></span></button>

    </div>
    <ul class="todolist">
      <li>Buy something new<span class="lnr lnr-trash"></span></li>
      <li>Buy something 2<span class="lnr lnr-trash"></span></li>
      <li>Buy something 3<span class="lnr lnr-trash"></span></li>
      <li>Buy something 4<span class="lnr lnr-trash"></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer">
      <span>You have 4 pending tasks</span>
      <button>Clear All</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Running the code in Node.js instead of opening the HTML document in a browser is the most likely cause.

Comment: "that's the same problem cause "document.querySelector" is not selecting anything", nope different causes. For the document issue as hinted by @Quentin your IDE is not correctly configured to act as a browser, but rather as a nodejs environment . For the console issue it's a simple typo: your `<input>` is referenced by the variable `inputBox` not `input`.

Comment: "Running the code in Node.js instead of opening the HTML document in a browser is the most likely cause. " - how do i go back to running it in the browser? @Quentin

Comment: File > Open File in the  browser typically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to reach `input` instead of `inputBox`. As well, `listArr` is not defined at all.

```
addBtn.onclick = () => {
  let userData = inputBox.value;
  let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("Todos");
  let listArr = getLocalStorage !== null ? JSON.parse(getLocalStorage) : [];
  listArr.push(userData);
  localStorage.setItem("Todos", JSON.stringify(listArr));
}
```